# Get favorite count for tag

Tags: feature-request, support, data-explorer, tag-watching

Is there a way to get the number of times a tag is favorited or the favorite tags for a user in Data Explorer?

It seems `Tags.Count` is the total number of questions with that tag.

`Count` won't work because there is for example 18k questions with the [list](/questions/tagged/list) tag, but it's only favorited 175 times.

If this is not currently possible, I suppose this is a feature request.

**Reason:**

I'm trying to identify questions that may have slipped through the cracks specifically due to bad tagging (that I could maybe answer or fix), `Tags.Count`, `ViewCount`, `Score`, `AcceptedAnswerId`, `AnswerCount` and `CommentCount` (in `Posts`, among others) can all play a role, but combining it with favorited tags seems like a better option.

Side note - does anyone know of such a query?

Comment: It's not currently possible... though having the information available would be great.

Comment: I assume [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308349/make-tag-follower-count-availabe-in-sede) is a cross-site duplicate?

Comment: A related feature request: [Let me get my favorite tags using data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271872).

Answer (score 3):

Favorite tags have been renamed to Tag Watching. It's now possible to see how many people are *watching* a specific tag by hovering it:

> [image]

Previously, it used to show how many people *subscribed* to the tag, but since the tag subscription feature has been removed, it's no longer relevant thus replaced with something more relevant.

Comment: still, watchers isn't in SEDE either which is what the OP asked.

Comment: @rene oh, good point. But the amount of user who favorited a tag before was never public in any way, as far as I remember.

Comment: That's correct. You can assume that every question that has the [tag:sede] tag and a comment from me but no answer means it can't be done with SEDE yet.

Comment: @rene you're very modest! :D

Comment: I know, right ;)

Comment: The old UI had a "subscribe" button, but [in place of "watchers" was "followers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312180/favorite-tags-is-now-tag-watching).