# How to find out how many users ignore a tag?

Tags: support, statistics, ignored-tags

When I hover a tag with the mouse, I see the number of followers (i.e. users who added that tag to their favorite tags list) in the popup:

> [image]

(As far as I know this is the only place where this information is displayed.)

Is there any way to obtain the number of people that ignore a tag?

This number is interesting, e.g., to estimate the popularity of a certain topic or type of question or how useful a tag is (after all, allowing people to ignore certain topics is one of the purposes of tags).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176321/get-favorite-count-for-tag

Comment: This has recently been [asked on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380340) as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Shog on a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380340) asked on Stack Overflow, this information is not available to users or moderators.

> "This isn't public information, at least as far as I'm aware." – [Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9)
>   *[permalink](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380346)*